# How can I automatically mount an external HD connected via USB to Airport Time Capsule every time I connect to my LAN?

Tags: time-machine, backup, airport, mount

I make Time Machine backups on an external 2TB HD connected via USB to my Airport Time Capsule.

**PROBLEM**

When I come back to home and I reconnect to my wi-fi LAN, Time Machine is not able to automatically reconnect to the backup volume (see image below).

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there any solution to enable Time Machine to reconnect automatically to external backup volume when I come back to home? ATTENTION: I do not need a solution to auto-mount at login/reboot, but rather a solution to auto-mount when I reconnect to my LAN. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without writing you a full blown Mac App, the best I can recommend is the app [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/)

As an addition/update to this, MarcoPolo is no longer maintained and the developer suggests using [control plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) if it is not working with your system.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks. If it works, it will be useful beyond this topic.